# turtle.ontimer() equivalent for tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program that requires the tkinter canvas to update graphics. In its previous form it was written in turtle. The turtle function to update the canvas is
    turtle.ontimer()
Is there a tkinter equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method:

For example:

```
root = Tk()

...

root.after(2000, callback) # call `callback` function in 2000 ms.
```